# Which refs, do I need to rewrite when trying to optimize a GitHub-hosted repository?

Tags: git-lfs

#### Background

We have a GitHub repository with a fairly large repository size because we have several framework binaries above 20mb in the history. This impacts CI times badly, as we're using hosted CI which is getting a fresh clone of the repository for every job.

To improve this, I want to rewrite the history and move large files to Git LFS.

#### Problem

I'm trying to use `git lfs migrate import` for this purpose.

As a preparation step I've tracked all remote branches locally, so that `--everything` is really going to rewrite everything and other developers on the team don't have to watch out for it, but can just get a fresh new clone.

When I rewrite history of a GitHub-hosted repository, do I need to rewrite and force push the references GitHub seems to be using to keep track of pull requests (`refs/pull/*`) as well?
`git lfs migrate import` has not included those as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to rewrite and force push the references GitHub seems to be using to keep track of pull requests (refs/pull/*) as well?

If you did need to, this would be a problem, because those references are read-only [according to Github's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/):

> The remote refs/pull/ namespace is read-only. If you try to push any commits there, you'll see this error:
>
> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/pull/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.local:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git'

Luckily, this isn't a problem, because any push to the original branch the Pull Request is asking to merge will [update the Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/):

> Once you've created a pull request, you can push commits from your topic branch to add them to your existing pull request. These commits will appear in chronological order within your pull request and the changes will be visible in the "Files changed" tab.

While it's not explicitly stated in that documentation, that includes force pushing to the branch - Github will detect the branch has been pointed to a new commit, and update the Pull Request with the new version.

Comment: I would be very interested by details about the last part of your answer. We have hundreds of PR that we'd like to keep after removing secrets and I'm trying to find a solution. But not sure how to implement your solution. I have a clean mirrored repo, a list of old and new commit ids. Should I checkout each branch and force push it with my new commit id somehow? I'm trying to find a way to force the PR to point to the new commit id.

Comment: @JulienN PRs track branches by name, so if you force push a commit to that remote branch, GitHub will pick it up. You don't have to check out the branch, you can use `git push --force origin abc123:refs/heads/mybranch` where `abc123` is your new commit (or branch name) and `mybranch` is the remote branch name. However, they have recently added *tracking* of force commits, so the old commit ID still shows up in the PR; presumably this also prevents it being garbage collected, so if you want to purge secrets you may be better off deleting the old branch completely and starting with a fresh name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did a few testing and you're right, GitHub keep references to all commits in the PR (not just head) so even if it was possible it would be a pain to replace...